# Ubuntu PPA for Android SDK/NDK?

Tags: android, sdk, deb

Has anyone bothered to create a PPA for the Android SDK and/or NDK packages?

I saw a few things that hinted at this in my Googling, but nothing that jumped out as a preferred solution.

I'd guess that licensing issues might require it to operate like the flash-installer (or more comparably, the google-earth) package, but it would be very useful. The SDK install OOB lacks many of the features that proper package management could bring in (dependencies, multi-user permissions/capability, etc.)

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question, but for an automated install you could try `wget`-ing the URL from https://developer.android.com/studio/ and unzipping it, or using a tool like ansible to do this on many machines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried [Upubuntu's guide](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/07/install-android-sdk-manager-revision-20.html)?

Comment: This looks to be it. Thank you.

Comment: nice... but why does it pull all the openjdk-6* packages when I already have sun-java6-jdk (also installed via ppa and registered as the only alternative)? And yes, i used `apt-get --no-install-recommends install android-sdk`.

Comment: Doesn't work on quantal anymore (?), repository is not found.

Comment: Upubuntu changed their launchpad account and ppa hierarchy. I took the liberty to edit the answer to link to the updated guide, still no packages for Quantal, though.

Comment: This is no longer valid

Answer (score 4):

try this , I'm a newbie , working on this.
I'm packaging these tools for Gajj Distro,

For Precise

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxgndu/gajj-sci
```

And for trusty

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxgndu/adt-raring 


    sudo apt-get update
```

For Android Developers Tool

```
    sudo apt-get install adt (Google may be ending eclipse plugin support, so this package may not be further maintained on this ppa, however you can check plugin updates from eclipse, using Help-> Install new software-> Then adding or selecting plugin repository.)
```

You also have to install Android-sdk

```
   sudo apt-get install android-sdk

   sudo sh /opt/android-sdk/install-sdk
```

(you may skip `sudo sh /opt/android-sdk/install-sdk` if you are installing android studio, bcz studio will automatically find the sdk on installion(first startup or you can manually set the path).)

For Android Studio

```
  sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Note: You may want to lock package version from synaptic package manager (or any) to prevent from downloading large updates by this ppa, bcz patches provided by Google are very small. This ppa is meant for installation purpose only.

---

You can also help me testing my package builds, bcz i'm newbie i don't know that much about ppa & packaging.

Hope this is it what you were asking for. :)

Comment: Hey, I used this method and got an error at the end related to update-alternatives, also sdk path were not set in the env. I am now struggling to fix it.

Comment: @rahoolm can you tell me exactly what happened, so that i can fix the problem.

Comment: i found it and fixed it, the error was bcz in previous packages sdk was in same package as android studio, but in 1.0.1, sdk will not be included in the package , you have to install it seprately, My recommendation before android studio.

Comment: OK Thanks. Also, when I installed it the latest android studio was not installed, so please do check that as well. With latest Android update it seems that sdk should not be a sub directory. Please do check that as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found no ppa so far, since the Upubuntu ppa is no longer updated and has no package for Quantal. But there is an `android-sdk` package in Backtrack Linux' repositories. As of 2012-12-25, this package claims to be the r20.0.3-bt0 version of the sdk nd there is an x64 build, but since I have not tested it, I know nothing else about it.

If you want to use this repository, [Ubuntubuzz has a tutorial on how to add them to Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/09/install-backtrack-5-application-in.html).